# Can you file only a federal tax return (and not state) if you're not required to in the first place?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

This is connected to my last question which you can find [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/104394/is-it-worth-filing-taxes?noredirect=1#comment194241_104394). To restate, I made $5,040 in "Wages, tips, and other compensation". Normally, I'm not required to file taxes, but I have decided to in order to get back the Federal taxes withheld. I was wondering, since I will get a $0 refund from my state and I don't owe anything to the state, is it OK if I only file a Federal tax return and not a state one? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.mass.gov/service-details/who-must-file-a-state-personal-income-tax-return

> If your Massachusetts gross income is less than $8,000, you don't have to file a Massachusetts tax return.

This applies to you, so you don't have to file.  The fact that you did decide to file a federal return is not relevant.